# How come a removable drive does not appear in Windows

Tags: windows, usb, device-manager

I have a 16GB Cruzer Fit FAT32 USB drive that works fine...most of the time. But every now and then it will not appear in Windows Explorer:

[image: No E drive]

If I right-click "My Computer" and choose Manage > Disk Management, the drive is visible and appears to be working fine:

[image: E drive in Disk Management]

I can also navigate to (and run standard commands like "dir" which work) in the Command Prompt:

[image: E drive in Command Prompt]

Finally, the device does appear in Device Manager:

[image: Cruzer Fit in Device Manager]

Unplugging and re-plugging the pen drive sometimes solves the problem. Any ideas why this might be happening? For example, could it be hard-ware related (metal USB port contacts becoming worn, say)?

Comment: Just an observation and I don't think it's actually the cause here, but I notice you have a lot of mapped drives. For some reason, Windows XP (Possibly later, I am not sure) doesn't check if there's a clash between a mapped drives and physical, so sometimes your devices can be hidden by a clashing mapped drive. What happens if you change the drive letter in Disk Management to F: for example, does it show up then? (Right click, change drive letter)

Comment: Have you tried using a different USB port when this happens?

Comment: Does [refreshing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc738376(v=ws.10).aspx) solve the problem?

Comment: @Jonno, this was solved in xp with a hotfix  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/297694

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. This happens on my work computer and I'll check all these out on my return in January. Vinayak: Fairly sure refreshing does not resolve this, but will check. Jonno: Don't think its the mapped network drives because the disk sometimes shows up fine, but this is nonetheless a good point. Possibly there is a subtle timing bug in Windows XP when many mapped drives are in use. DavidPostill: No, haven't tried a different port but will give it a go. Unplugging and replugging on the same port does usually solve the issue, though.